# UIViews in scrollviews

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, grid

I have a `UIScrollview` with `UIView`, and in every `UIView` has a labels and image. I'm looping this view and it's working fine, but I have a button `Grid` and when i press this they changed into grid view. The problem is the last item is not working fine as the others. One of the labels are hidden in the last item. And when I pressed the list view button, the last item has a problem again, the labels are complete but the 'View' didn't changed.

-update.

the content size is okay, and it's leaving a space for the last item but the last item is somewhere. I can't post images yet because of the reputation.

`-(void)actionList {

```
int prods = 0;
isGrid = NO;
for(UIView*iView in sv_results.subviews){
    for(UILabel *iView2 in iView.subviews){

        if([iView2 isMemberOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
            if(iView2.tag == 0)
            {
                iView2.frame = CGRectMake(80, 0, 150, 50);
                iView2.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f];
                NSLog(@"%@",iView2.text);
            }
            else if(iView2.tag == 1)
            {
                pricewidth = [iView2.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f]}];
                iView2.frame = CGRectMake(80, 20, pricewidth.width+1, 50);
                iView2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f];
                for(UIView *discountline in iView2.subviews)
                {
                    discountline.frame = CGRectMake(0, iView2.frame.size.height/2, iView2.frame.size.width, 1);
                }
            }
            else if(iView2.tag == 2)
            {
                iView2.frame = CGRectMake(screenRect.size.width-60, 30, 50, 15);
                iView2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0f];
            }
            else if(iView2.tag == 3)
            {
                iView2.frame = CGRectMake(140, 20, 150, 50);
                iView2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f];
            }
        }

        if([iView2 isMemberOfClass:[AsyncImageView class]]){
            iView2.frame = CGRectMake(15,12,50,50);
            iView2.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

        }
    }

    NSLog(@"all avail data > %i",allAvailableData);
    for(int i = 0;i<allAvailableData;i++)
    {
        if(iView.tag == i)
        {
            NSLog(@"UIView tag > %i",iView.tag);
            iView.frame = CGRectMake(0,((i-1)*75),320,75);
        }
    }

    prods++;
    iView.layer.borderWidth = .3f;
}
NSLog(@"%i",prods);
sv_results.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,(allAvailableData)*75);
```

}`

Comment: add screen shots and share some code so we can help you??

Comment: check contentSize of uiscrollview